# Error "not coding-compliant" for XIB VC IBOutlet's

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x101664480> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label.'`
Why do I get this error when I connect an IBOutlet like so;
`@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!`
    `func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label.text = "Hello World!"
}`

The xib's file's owner is set to the custom UIViewController class
**Is it something special for UIViewController + xib ?**
[Connected IBOutlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJRCU.png)

Ignore `import NightNight`
[Outlets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QhGG.png)
**The VC is loaded via this func in a UITableView;**
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let topicVCName = UIViewController(nibName: categories[indexPath.section].refName[indexPath.row], bundle: nil)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(topicVCName, animated: true)
}`
If I take away the outlets the xib loads fine with no errors. *(Obviously)*

Comment: you have broke label reference outlets, look at it in xib

Comment: please use inspector and check again

Comment: Added image of outlets

Comment: Press ⇧⌘F, type `label`, press return, look at the search results and fix the issue.

Comment: That pointed me to the file's owners outlet

Comment: Try to disconnect and reconnect the outlet.

Comment: Done that still no use @vadian

Comment: How are you loading your `SingleNumberVC` and its associated `XIB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the error message:

```
UIViewController 0x101664480
```

This proves that your view controller in the storyboard (or wherever the view controller itself comes from) is a plain vanilla UIViewController and not a SingleNumberVC. It is true that SingleNumberVC has a `label` property, but UIViewController does not!

You have said:

> xib's file's owner is set to the custom UIViewController class

Indeed, because otherwise you could not have formed the outlet at all. But when the code runs, the view controller *itself* is not the custom UIViewController class. You did not answer the question of where it comes from, but I assure you, wherever that is, you will find you have forgotten to specify SingleNumberVC.

**EDIT** Oh, I see, here it is:

```
let topicVCName = UIViewController(nibName: categories[indexPath.section].refName[indexPath.row], bundle: nil)
```

Change `UIViewController` to `SingleNumberVC` in that line.

Comment: That makes sense! So in the `didSelectRowAt` should the constant "topicVCName" not be UIViewController(....) and instead be SingleNumberVC(....)? @matt

Comment: That makes sense too. But that will only `pushViewController ` to `SingleNumberVC` and I have more VC's than just `SingleNumberVC`... How would you do this?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. I answered the question you _asked_. I told you (correctly) what the crash means and how to make the crash go away.